# Integral Domain and no nonzero divisors Proof

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove that a commutative ring is an integral domain if and only if it has no nonzero zero divisors.

I think my main problem is that I'm getting jumbled in the wording! By 'no nonzero zero divisors' it's saying that the ring is an integral domain if and only if it HAS zero divisors.

My idea:
Let a commutative ring D be an integral domain and suppose there exist zero divisors. Therefore, there is an element $a \in D$ which is a zero divisor and there is a $b \in D$* such that ab=0.

Because it's an iff statement I have to prove it coming from the other way as well so I would have something like...

Let D be a ring such that there are no nonzero zero divisors. Then I will want to show that D is cancellative under the multiplication operation, which is just that ab=ac implies b=c.

I just need help verifying what exactly I need to show and how to apply the definition of cancellative and the definition of zero divisors.

Comment: What's **your** efinition of *integral Domain* ?

Comment: @Don Presumably nonzero elts are cancellative

Comment: "By 'no nonzero zero divisors' it's saying that the ring is an integral domain if and only if it HAS zero divisors." - No. Forget the word 'nonzero' for a second and look at it again. Nonzero should be included in the definition of zero divisor.

Comment: The questions is saying that a commutative ring $R$ is an integral domain if and only if $\forall a,b\in R\mid ab=0\implies (a=0\text{ or } b=0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\,a\,$ is not a zero-divisor, $\,ab = ac\,\Rightarrow\,a(b\!-\!c) = 0\,\Rightarrow\,b\!-\!c=0\,\Rightarrow\,b = c,\,$ so $\,a\,$ is cancellative.

Conversely, if $\,a\,$ is cancellative then $\,ab = 0 = a\cdot 0\,\Rightarrow\,b=0,\,$ so $\,a\,$ is not a zero-divisor.